# Why doesn't every square matrix have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors? [Strang P310 6.1.26]

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

**Curt Solution:** First reason: The nullspace and column space can overlap, so $\mathbf{x}$ could be in both. Second reason: There may not be $r$ independent eigenvectors in the column space.

**[Longer Solution (cp P11)](http://www.math.utah.edu/~zwick/Classes/Fall2012_2270/Assignments/Assignment11_Solutions.pdf):** [image]

$\Large{{1.}}$ The longer solution proves $A$'s eigenvectors $= \{\mathbf{x}\} = \operatorname{span}\{ \, (1, 0)^T\, \} \in \ker(A) \cap \operatorname{colspace}(A).$ Still, I don't seize the problem(s)? Also, how do the first three sentences on the $4$ subspaces relate?

$\Large{{2.}}$ $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \dim(\operatorname{colspace})(A) = \begin{cases} r = n, \text{ if the columns of $A$ are linearly independent.} \\  r < n, \text{ if the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent.}\end{cases}$
I remember this, but how does this pertain to the Curt Solution's second reason?

$3.$ What's the intuition behind these two reasons?

Comment: I changed \operatorname{ker} to \ker and \operatorname{dim(colspace)} to \dim(\operatorname{colspace}). Both \dim and \ker are standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The longer solution doesn't even seem to address the question. Why does it even need to bring up the fact that the spaces are orthogonal (or not)?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thank you! Please feel free to emend anything else.

Comment: @EuYu: I'm equally bewildered by the longer solution. Is it irrelative?

Comment: @LePressentiment The longer solution indeed feels irrelevant. Subspaces being orthogonal complements is a _strong_ condition. Certainly subspaces being orthogonal is sufficient to conclude them being disjoint, but most disjoint subspaces are far from being orthogonal. Therefore mentioning that the columnspace and the nullspace are not orthogonal says nothing about whether they overlap or not. I feel like the solution addresses a different question, are you sure it is a solution to _this_ problem?